# How to install php curl?

Tags: php, curl, apt

I am trying to install php curl like so:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

But I keep getting an error.

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done php5-curl is already the newest version. 0
>   upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded. 2 not
>   fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional
>   disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y Setting up
>   runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ... start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed
>   to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused dpkg:
>   error processing package runit (--configure):  subprocess installed
>   post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency
>   problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:  git-daemon-run
>   depends on runit; however:   Package runit is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure): 
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written
>   because the error message indicates its a followup error from a
>   previous failure.
>                             Errors were encountered while processing:
>
> runit  git-daemon-run E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error
>   code (1)

when I try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I get:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run: 
>   git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:   Package runit is not
>   configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure): 
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered
>   while processing:  git-daemon-run

when I try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall runit` I get:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1
>   reinstalled, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded. 2 not fully installed or
>   removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be
>   used. E: Internal Error, No file name for runit:amd64

when I try `sudo apt-get install runit` I get:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done runit is already the newest version. 0
>   upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded. 2 not
>   fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional
>   disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y Setting up
>   runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ... start: Job is already running: runsvdir
>   dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):  subprocess
>   installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg:
>   dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run: 
>   git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:   Package runit is not
>   configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure): 
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written
>   because the error message indicates its a followup error from a
>   previous failure.
>                                                                                                             Errors were encountered while processing:  runit  git-daemon-run E:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

when I try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall git-daemon-run` I get:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1
>   reinstalled, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded. 2 not fully installed or
>   removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be
>   used. E: Internal Error, No file name for git-daemon-run:amd64

How can I fix this?

System Specs:

- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD TURKS (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.6.2)
- OS Type: Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check solution from https://askubuntu.com/questions/631615/problems-with-git-all-and-15-04

You'll need to forcibly remove `runit`. Running `sudo dpkg -r runit` should work. You might need to use one of the `--force-*` options.

Comment: yes I had to use force like so **sudo dpkg -r --force-all runit**